# JPA does not write to table

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jboss6.x

I have the following JPA code, with all the values checked (`ticket` contains a valid bean, it ends without exception, etc.) It is executed, it does not throw any exceptions, yet in the end no data is written into the table.

I tried also retrieving a bean from the table, it also "works" (it is empty, so no data is returned).

The setup is

- JBoss 6.1 Final
- SQLServer 2008 Express (driver SQL JDBC 3 from MS)

The persistence code:

```
public String saveTicket() {
  System.out.println("Controller saveTicket() ");
  EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GesMan"); /* I know it would be better to share a single instance of factory, this is just for testing */
  EntityManager entityMan = factory.createEntityManager();
  entityMan.persist(this.ticket);
  entityMan.close();
}
```

The persistence unit is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="GesMan" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/GesManDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>es.caib.gesma.gesman.Ticket</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
      value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The datasource

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>GesManDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://spsigeswnt14.caib.es:1433;DatabaseName=TEST_GESMAN</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <user-name>thisis</user-name>
    <password>notthepassword</password>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT * FROM dbo.Ticket</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <metadata>
      <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it looks like I was using the wrong approach.... In JBoss you can`t (better said, I could not get to) access JPA directly (as you would do in JSE).

I ended creating an EJB (with transactions) and passing all JPA logic there.

PS: Of course, if I am wrong please tell me (now it is more of an academic issue, but still I want to know)

Answer (score 0):

call `entityMan.flush()` or `transaction.commit()` befor closing it, otherwise it will discard all changes queued on close.

Comment: flush caused an exception telling me that it needed to be inside a transaction; and I could not manually begin a transaction (I needed to setup EJBs and let the container work it out).

Comment: How did you configure the transaction management? Is it container-managed or bean-managed?